# MySQL DATETIME Getting Number of Days and sorting

Tags: mysql

For a project of mine, I want to get only the days of the dates found in the database. Then rank those closest to the current day.

Date Type: DATETIME

For example: Sunday (1st day)

How can I list the dates containing the nearest day based on the current day?

I looked through past questions but couldn't find a similar question.

Comment: please provide the example which can understand by viewers

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/)